# Shibboleth not receive attribute in HTTP headers

Tags: apache, http, header, shibboleth

When I access my secure page, after logging in, I expect to see the data of my logged in user in the header. I can't see them.
This is my apache file:

```
<Location /VerificaGel/protected>
        ShibRequestSetting applicationId VerificaGel
        AuthType shibboleth
        ShibRequireSession On
        ShibUseHeaders On
        require shibboleth


</Location>
```

from here it is enabled.
These are the tags of my shibboleth2.xml file

```
<RequestMapper type="Native">
        <RequestMap applicationId="default">
        <Host name="verificagel.integrazione.lispa.it" scheme="https" port="443" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true" exportAssertion="true">
    <!--    <Host name="verificagel.integrazione.lispa.it" scheme="http" port="80" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true" exportAssertion="true"> -->
            <Path name="/VerificaGel/protected" applicationId="VerificaGel" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true" exportAssertion="true"/>
        </Host>

        </RequestMap>
    </RequestMapper>
...
    <ApplicationDefaults entityID="https://shib-test.gpi.it/shibboleth"
        REMOTE_USER="eppn subject-id pairwise-id persistent-id"
        cipherSuites="DEFAULT:!EXP:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL:!DES:!IDEA:!SEED:!RC4:!3DES:!kRSA:!SSLv2:!SSLv3:!TLSv1:!TLSv1.1">
```

I don't know where I went wrong.
If I run https://myurl/Shibboleth.sso/Status
I get the values but I can't retrieve them in the http header.
Can you help me? Thank you